# Convergence of discretized process when its predictable part converges to infinite variation process

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, limits-and-convergence

This question seems to be related to Theorem IX.7.28 in [J. Jacod and A. Shiryaev's *Limit theorems for stochastic processes* (2013)](https://www.google.co.kr/books/edition/Limit_Theorems_for_Stochastic_Processes/mSD4CAAAQBAJ?hl=ko&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover), and it is very important to prove asymptotic properties of my statistical estimator.
The situation can be much like simplified as follows.

**Here is a question.**

Let our discretized process be
\begin{align}
 X^n_t = \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \left(W_{\frac{i}{n}} - W_{\frac{i-2}{n}}\right),
\end{align}
where $W$ is a standard Wiener process.
My intuition says that it would converge stably in law to $2W$ (in the Skorokhod space $\mathbb{D}([0,1])$), i.e.,
\begin{align}
X^n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}-s} 2W.
\end{align}
But I'm not sure it is ok to apply Theorem IX.7.28 to show this, because the predictable part (denote it as $B^n_t$) converges to Wiener process itself which has "infinite variation":
\begin{align}
B^n_t &:= \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{E}_{\frac{i-1}{n}} \left[ W_{\frac{i}{n}} - W_{\frac{i-2}{n}} \right]  \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \left(W_{\frac{i-1}{n}} - W_{\frac{i-2}{n}}\right)  \\
&= W_{\frac{[(n-1)t]}{n}} \xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} W_t,
\end{align}
while Jacod and Shiryaev's theorem says that $B^n_t$ should converge to a predictable "finite variation" process $B_t$.
So how can I show this?

**Here is a theorem.**

Without considering the truncation function or jumps of $X$, the theorem says:

> **IX.7.28 Theorem.** For every càdlàg process $X$, we use the following notation:
> \begin{align*}
> X_t^n = X_{[nt]/n},\qquad\qquad \Delta_i^n X = X_{i/n} - X_{(i-1)/n} = \Delta X^n_{i/n},
> \end{align*}
> We also consider the discretized process of the form
> \begin{align*}
> X_t^n = \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \chi_i^n,
> \end{align*}
> where each $\chi_i^n$ is $\mathcal{F}_{i/n}$-measurable.
> Assume that each $\chi_i^n$ is square-integrable, and $X$ is a continuous and $\mathbb{E}[|X_t|^2] < \infty$ for all $t$ with the canonical decomposition $X_t = B_t + M_t$ where $B_t$ is predictable finite variation process and $M_t$ is square-integrable local martingale.
>
> Suppose also that for all $t>0$ and all uniformly integrable martingale $N$ which are orthogonal to $X$ we have
> \begin{align*}
> \sup_t \left| \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{E} _{\frac{i-1}{n}}[\chi_i^n] - B_t \right| &\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0,  \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{V}_{\frac{i-1}{n}}[\chi_i^n] &\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} \langle M, M \rangle_t + \langle w \cdot W', w \cdot W' \rangle_t \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{E}_{\frac{i-1}{n}}[\chi_i^n \Delta_i^n M] &\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} \langle M, M \rangle_t,  \\
> \sum_{i=1}^{[nt]} \mathbb{E}_{\frac{i-1}{n}}[\chi_i^n \Delta_i^n N] &\xrightarrow{\mathbb{P}} 0.
> \end{align*}
> Then there is a very good canonical Wiener extension of $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \{\mathcal{F}_t\}, \mathbb{P})$ with Wiener process $W'$ and a continuous $X$-biased $\mathcal{F}$-progressive conditional martingale PII $X'$ on this extension such that
> \begin{align*}
> X^n \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}-s} X' = X + w \cdot W',
> \end{align*}
> where $w \cdot W' = \int w\,dW'$  and $w$ is a predictable process.

If I have any misunderstanding please let me know.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "converge stably"? Also, converge in what space, specifically?

Comment: Stable convergence means $(X^n,Y) \xrightarrow{\mathcal{L}} (X,Y)$ for any measurable r.v. $Y$. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/211705/245384) is a precise definition.

Comment: To define the convergence in law in your comment, you still need to specify the topological space in which the paths of the processes $X^n$ lie.

Comment: The convergence is in Skorokhod topology sense.

Comment: Over the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes! over the interval [0,1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h_i:=W_{i/n}-W_{(i-1)/n}$ and $n_t:=\lfloor nt\rfloor$, so that $t-1/n\le n_t/n\le t$. Then
$$X^n_t=\sum_{i=1}^{n_t}(h_{i-1}+h_i)
=\sum_{i=1}^{n_t}h_{i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n_t}h_i=W_{n_t/n-1/n}-W_{-1/n}+W_{n_t/n},$$
whence
$$|X^n_t-2W_t|\le|W_{n_t/n-1/n}-W_t|+|W_{-1/n}|+|W_{n_t/n}-W_t|$$
and, for each real $u>0$,
$$P(\sup_{0\le t\le 1}|X^n_t-2W_t|>3u)\le2nP(\max_{0\le s\le2/n}|W_s|>u)+P(|W_{-1/n}|>u).$$
Next, $P(|W_{-1/n}|>u)=P(|W_1|>u\sqrt n)\to0$ (as $n\to\infty$) and
$$
\begin{aligned}
2nP(\max_{0\le s\le2/n}|W_s|>u)
&=2nP(\max_{0\le t\le1}|W_t|>u\sqrt{n/2}) \\ 
&\le2nP(\max_{0\le t\le1}W_t>u\sqrt{n/2}) \\ 
&=4nP(W_1>u\sqrt{n/2}) \\ 
&\le2n\exp\{-u^2n/4)\to0.
\end{aligned}
$$
So, $X^n\to2W$ in probability in $C[0,1]$ and hence in probability in $D[0,1]$ and hence stably in $D[0,1]$, as desired.